# What is the term to describe the percentage of users that don't proceed from one page to another?

Tags: terminology, analytics

What is the term used to describe the percentage of users that don't continue in a flow?

For example, if only 50% of users go from the login screen to the profile screen, what do you call that?

Answer (score 17):

It depends on the context, but these are often used interchangeably.

**A few options are:**

- bounce rate (if initial page)
- drop-off rate (not initial page)
- exit rate (not initial page)
- [abandonment rate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abandonment_rate) (specific to e-commerce)

---

**More on the distinctions (from a web analytics standpoint) on:**

- [Bounce Rate vs. Exit Rate](http://getdelve.com/2012/09/bounce-rate-vs-exit-rate-whats-the-difference/)
- [Bounce Rate vs. Drop-Off](http://www.rankraiser.com/rankraiser/difference-between-google-bounce-rate-and-drop-offs/)
- Google Analytics on [Bounce Rate vs. Drop-Off](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2525491?hl=en)

Comment: I'd like to add `exit rate`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Paul! I added it to the answer.

Answer (score 6):

There are definitely a lot of terms for it and it really depends on the context.

In many cases you have a new user funnel. There may be a certain step that you may consider that user an customers, player (if a game), etc.  That would be the **conversion rate**.

If you don't have a flow and you have users coming to the page and leaving immediately, that would often be referred to as the **bounce rate**.

If you have a custom flow as you are describing. This is often called the **drop-off rate**.

In some flows, especially if dealing with subscriptions (mobile / social apps included) this would be considered as the **churn rate** as users leave and never come back / remove the app.